# Gnuplot, how to plot data from a file .dat (No data in plot problem)

Tags: windows, file, plot, windows-10, gnuplot

I am using Gnuplot on windows 10, I need to plot some file excel and to do that I copied and pasted evrything in a .dat file (ANSI), but everytime I try to do a simple plot (I mean the only "plot" command) I have this " warning: Cannot find or open file "FolderWhereFileIsLocated/filetoplot.dat"
         No data in plot
And of course it is not empty, the file contains this: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gQZMl.png)

The file is saved as a .dat , I've also checked many questions about issues like this but I did not have solved, I've also tried to download from the web some other .dat files to test them but without any results.

Can someone please explain me step by step what can I do to make Gnuplot plot my .dat files?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: please provide the exact gnuplot code you are using. What do you get when you type `pwd` in the gnuplot console? This should show your current working directory.

Answer (score 1):

You should take care that your columns are properly separated. In the image you attached are a bunch of white spaces and then a comma separated pair of values, or do you use the comma as decimal symbol?
Save the spreadsheet directly using excel (eg. as csv type and name it *.dat if you want to have it ending like this) and then try to plot it once more.